# What is -0.0 in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have been working on finding a parabola with three points by using the determinant method. 
The coefficients that are returned are sometimes

> **-0.0000**

What does this mean? Why  is there a negative sign and what does it signify?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `format long g` to see more significant digits. The number is probably very slightly negative.

Comment: +1: and in some cases you'd want to round these to an exact 0.

Comment: Although, the concept of `-0` does exist: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/15/why-computers-have-signed-zero/